# Create request model web api

Tags: c#, .net, api, model, http-post

I am trying to create an appointment type request class. This will receive from the user a date, in dd/mm/yyyy format and a time in hh/mm format. How could I configure this request class? I did the one below but it's not ok, it gives me an error when formatting JSON

```
public class CreateAppointmentRequestModel
{
    Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm:ss}")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can set both of your date and time in DataTime structure why do you want to set them in two property?

Comment: Because i want from user to add for one time the date and the second time the hour and minute of the appointment

Comment: `"it gives me an error when formatting JSON"` How did you send request? What's the error details? You can use [FromForm] format to sent your request with your current request model.